# How do I append custom data in the body of a xmpp message in ejabberd

Tags: xml, xmpp, chat, ejabberd, ejabberd-hooks

I have set up a chat settong using Pidgin and Ejabberd.I have written down a custom module in ejabberd using `user_send_packet`:

```
ejabberd_hooks:add(user_send_packet, _Host, ?MODULE,
           myMessage, 95),
```

The function myMessage is as follows:

```
myMessage({Packet, C2SState})->


PacketType=xmpp:get_name(Packet),
case PacketType of
<<"iq">>->
ok;
<<"presence">>->
ok;
<<"message">>->

Sum=2+2,
?INFO_MSG("Sum is ~p~n",[Sum])

end,

{Packet,C2SState}.
```

Basically what this function does is that whenever someone sends a chat message say "hello there", the value of `Sum` gets calculated and printed on the server and its logs and the message ""hello there" is sent to the second user.

But Now I want send the value of `Sum` along with the message `"hello there"` to the second user for example:

```
"hello there Sum is 4"
```

Can anyone help me out with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is:

```
process_message({#message{body = Body} = Msg, C2SState})->
    Sum = calc_sum_and_return_as_binary(),
    NewBody = lists:map(
        fun(#text{data = Data} = Txt) ->
            Txt#text{data = <<Data/binary, Sum/binary>>}
        end, Body),
    {Msg#message{body = NewBody}, C2SState};
process_message(Acc) ->
    Acc.
```

Note, that `#text{}` record contains `lang` field which can be used if you want to support internationalization of the text being appended.

Comment: Thank you for the reply first. I used the code snippet given by you and observed the following things:Firstly Sum=4 was not getting converted into binary since Sum is a variable, then I used Sum=[4] but the user to whom this message was sent closed the connection and restarted it with the message "Connection reset by peer". Then I tried  Sum="4", Sum=["4"] and Sum ="[4]" which were all successful and sent the messages as 4,4 and [4] respectively.Then I have learnt that in erlang string is nothing but a list only so thinking that I used Sum=[[4]] but it went to the connection reset again.

Comment: So I want to ask two things:(1)how can I send just Sum=[4] as a message to be received as [4] ?        and         (2) Is it neccessary to enclose each sending message under double inverted commas "" to be sent as a message?

Comment: Look, these are simple Erlang questions, you're better off spending a couple of hours learning simple Erlang tutorial to clarify these things.

Comment: Simply put, if you want to append "[4]" text, you should do the following:
Sum = list_to_binary([$[, integer_to_list(2+2), $]])