# How do I append custom data in the body of a xmpp message in ejabberd?

Tags: xmpp, xml, ejabberd, instant-messaging

I have set up a chat setting using Pidgin and Ejabberd. I have written a custom module in ejabberd using the `user_send_packet` hook:

```erlang
ejabberd_hooks:add(user_send_packet, _Host, ?MODULE,
           myMessage, 95),
```

The function `myMessage` is as follows:

```erlang
myMessage({Packet, C2SState})->

  PacketType=xmpp:get_name(Packet),
  case PacketType of
    <<"iq">>->
      ok;
    <<"presence">>->
      ok;
    <<"message">>->
      Sum=2+2,
      ?INFO_MSG("Sum is ~p~n",[Sum])
  end,

  {Packet,C2SState}.
```

Basically what this function does is that whenever someone sends a chat message say `"hello there"`, the value of Sum gets calculated and printed on the server and its logs and the message `"hello there"` is sent to the second user.

But now I want send the value of Sum along with the message "hello there" to the second user for example:

```
"hello there Sum is 4"
```

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: it has been already answered at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45455387/how-do-i-append-custom-data-in-the-body-of-a-xmpp-message-in-ejabberd).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I append custom data in the body of a xmpp message in ejabberd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45455387/how-do-i-append-custom-data-in-the-body-of-a-xmpp-message-in-ejabberd)